# error in msgrcv() :receiving data through message queue in C

Tags: c, linux, ipc, message-queue, msgrcv

I am sending message using message queue mechanism in C linux. But there is some problem with the msgrcv function. It's showing error as invalid argument.
Please check this.

```
//msgrcv.c
#include"msgbuf.h"
int main()
{
      int msqid;
      key_t key;
      message_buf  *rbuf;
      rbuf=malloc(sizeof(*rbuf));
     // rbuf->m=malloc(sizeof(M1));

      key = ftok("/home/user",'a');
      if ((msqid = msgget(key, IPC_CREAT)) ==(key)-1)
      {
         perror("msgget");
         exit(1);
      }

      /* Receive an answer of message type 1.   */
      if (msgrcv(msqid, &rbuf, sizeof(rbuf->m), 1, 0) < 0)
      {
           perror("msgrcv");  //invalid argument to msgrcv
           exit(1);
       }
         /* Print the answer.  */
       printf("Received message text= %s\n", rbuf->m.cp);
      return 0;
   }
```

now msgbuf.h

```
 //msgbuf.h
typedef struct msgclient
{
   int msglen;
   int msgtype;
   char *cp;
}M1;

typedef struct msgbuf1
{
   long    mtype;
   M1      m;
} message_buf;
```

I also would like to know how two way comm happen using message queue. Do I need to make two message queues to get communication done between two processes? sample code for the same is also welcomed.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this

```
if ((msqid = msgget(key, 0666)) ==key-1)
```

should be

```
if ((msqid = msgget(key, 0666)) == -1)
```

From [`msgrcv`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/msgrcv.html)

> **ERRORS**
>   The msgrcv() function will fail if:
>   ...
>   [EINVAL]
>       *msqid* is not a valid message queue identifier.

Furthermore, `message_buf.m` must not be a pointer but a member

```
typedef struct msgbuf1
{
   long    mtype;
   M1      m;
} message_buf;
```

You can then save this call to `malloc`

```
rbuf->m=malloc(sizeof(M1));
```

and the call to `msgrcv` should be

```
if (msgrcv(msqid, rbuf, sizeof(rbuf->m), 1, 0) < 0)
```

because otherwise, `msgrcv` will overwrite your stack.

*Update:*

From [`msgget`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/msgget.html)

> **ERRORS**
>   [ENOENT]
>       A message queue identifier does not exist for the argument key and (msgflg & IPC_CREAT) is 0.

This means, you must call

```
if ((msqid = msgget(key, IPC_CREAT | 0666)) == -1)
```

at least for the first time you call this function.

Comment: no sir. It's giving error with msgget() rather after doing the above change.

Comment: In your question, you say `msgrcv`. Do you get an error with `msgget` or with `msgrcv`?

Comment: **msgrcv: Invalid argument**  This is what I am getting as I do ./a.out after compiling.

Comment: yes. I think msqid is creating problem. Any idea how to generate it?

Comment: Fix the `if (msgget(...) == -1)` and see the return value. The creation itself looks fine.

Comment: its returning -1 every time.

Comment: **msgget: No such file or directory**

Comment: Updation made. Still **msgrcv: Permission denied** . However if do **msqid=msgget(key,IPC_CREAT|0666)** It's giving msqid as -1.

Comment: Then the problem is still with msgget and you should see what error msgget returns. You can use the command ipcs to see what message queues exist.

Answer (score 0):

I see one massive problem already:

```
message_buf  *rbuf;
rbuf=malloc(sizeof(rbuf));
```

Since `rbuf` is a *pointer,* you should be using

```
rbuf=malloc(sizeof(*rbuf));
```

Your original gives you the size of the pointer (usually four or eight bytes in current compilers) rather than the size of the `message_buf` structure that you need.

Another problem is your comparison with `key-1` which I beleive should be `(key)-1`.

It's possible that your `msgget` is failing and, because of this faulty check, you're not detecting it. That means the `msgrecv` would be using `-1` as the queue ID, explaining the failure there.

Comment: I said that was one problem, there may be others. Regardless, it needs fixing to prevent undefined behaviour.

Comment: yes. got it.  :) but the error with msgrcv is still there. **msgrcv: Invalid argument**

Comment: Check the update, your msgget check is faulty so a failure there would cause the msgrecv to fail.

Comment: Updation made. Still **msgrcv: Permission denied** . However if do **msqid=msgget(key,IPC_CREAT|0666)** It's giving msqid as -1.

Comment: That's a different error, this quuestion is answered, it's not meant to be conversational. I suggest you ask a new question with the new problem.